# How to properly use Cocos2d's update/tick method to trigger an event, only once?

Tags: methods, triggers, cocos2d-iphone, boolean

I keep running into this issue wherein I'd like to trigger an event (void) during a scheduled update or tick method - but only trigger it once.  The problem is that it gets triggered every time update/tick gets called (each frame). Depending on what method is being called, this slows down the game and occasionally crashes (e.g. addChild already added).  I've used a BOOL (e.g. eventTriggered) before to try to handle this situation but am wondering if that is the only and/or best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using cocos2d 2.0 just use:

```
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(yourMethod:) delay:3.0f];
```

In all other cases simply unschedule the scheduled selector:

```
-(void) yourScheduledMethodThatShouldOnlyRunOnce:(ccTime)delta
{
    [self unschedule:_cmd];

    // do stuff once
}
```

If it's a custom method you need to have some condition that fires the method call, for example:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    if (runThisNowButOnlyOnce)
    {
        runThisNowButOnlyOnce = NO;
        [self runThisNowButOnlyOnceMethod];
    }
}
```

You just need to figure out when and where to set runThisNowButOnlyOnce to YES. Also don't forget to add it as an ivar to the @interface.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I shouldn't worry about this "CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.0000 to 0.0000"

Comment: Hi! I'm using `[self scheduleOnce:@selector(myMethod:) delay:3.0f];` and my method gets called more than once.. can you wonder what's going on?? thanks

Comment: I can wonder, yes. Wondering whether maybe you call scheduleOnce more than once?